# Set and Get the class field(s) using Delegate in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, delegation

How to use Delegate for class field getters & setters? Trying to set and get fields(may be some more execution while getting & setting)  in Kotlin.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class Example {
    var p: String by Delegate()

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "toString:" + p
    }
}

class Delegate() {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>): String {
        //Something like this :prop.get(thisRef)
       return "value"
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: String) {

        //something like this : prop.set(thisRef, value)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val e = Example()
    println(e.p)//blank output
    e.p = "NEW"
    println(e.p)//NEW should be the output
}
```

Tutorial : https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Delegated%20properties/Custom%20delegate/Custom%20delegate.kt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't get a backing field for your delegate's value by default, because it might not store an actual value, or it may store many different values. If you want to store a single `String` here, you can create a property for it in your delegate:

```
class Delegate {
    private var myValue: String = ""

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>): String {
        return myValue
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        myValue = value
    }
}
```

Comment: So does that mean, Delegates are not re-usable for different properties? Actually, I was thinking that we need not create separate field inside Delegate class to set/get the property of the delegated class. What I don't get is, what implementation should I give to getValue()/setValue() functions for those cases ?

Comment: Yes, multiple properties are not supposed to be backed by the same delegate instance. How you implement your delegate internally is up to you. It can store values in its own private properties, it can store them on a server somewhere, it can just return constants or random values every time it's accessed. The language doesn't prescribe any implementation, it just enables you to read and write values stored in the delegate with a simple syntax as if they were in a regular property.

Comment: Okay. So in the example I posted if I want "e.p = "NEW" to reflect on println(e.p), I would need to have string field inside PropDelegate and set & get that field. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct, and that's what the implementation in my answer does.

Comment: Great, got it. Thanks.

Comment: if that's case, what is the use of  parameter [thisRef:Any?] and [prop: KProperty] @zsmb13